# Authentication failure with rdrop2

Tags: r, dropbox

I have been using rdrop2 with relative success over the last few months. However, I recently returned from being away and nothing is working.

When I attempt to authenticate interactively via R, everything appears to go well. But when I run the command

```
drop_auth()
```

it returns

```
       error
1 v1_retired
```

I think this stems from dropbox retiring the [first version of their api and moving onto version 2.](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/)

Do I need to change something in my process of authentication to fix this? If so, what do I need to do? 
Or is this more fundamental to the rdrop2 library?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the use of the now retired version of the Dropbox API. There's apparently an updated version of rdrop2 that uses the current version of the Dropbox API instead. More details here:

https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2/issues/152